# Can you use keyframes in react to animate objects?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make in image spin, yet when I use keyframes it doesn't spin. So my question is it even possible to use keyframes in react?

**CSS CODE BELOW**

```
 .logoImage {
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
@-moz-keyframes spin { 100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@-webkit-keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } }
@keyframes spin { 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); } }
 }
```

Comment: React is not limiting you from using things like this, under the hood its just vanilla js that's running. How are you rendering the element with this class? Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Can you provide the React code where you have the `.logoImage` class applied?

Comment: You are declaring the keyframes wrong. They need to be defined outside of the class notation.

Comment: @jered John Ruddell has already answered my question so I will not be posting the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css, you need to define the keyframes outside of the CSS class definition

```
.logoImage {
    -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
    animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
 }

@-moz-keyframes spin { 
  0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }
}
```

[See it live!](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-slt57)

Comment: Yep! happy to help :) Just remember, React doesn't limit you, you can do just about anything in react because you have a lot of control! :)